# Compatibility layers vs. virtualization layers

Tags: cygwin, compatibility, virtualization, wine

If you read Wikipedia articles about [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)), [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and [CrossOver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrossOver_(software)), you will see that this software is classified as "[compatibility layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_layer)".

I'm trying to understand what compatibility layer is from the point of view of virtualization layers. I mean, does it use:

- library-level virtualization; or...
- application-level virtualization; or...
- some different-level virtualization (which one?)
- and does it use virtualization at all?

Answer (score 1):

It does NOT use any virtulization.
The cygwin1.dll provides a C Library and the Posix compatibility layer,
between the program and the underhood Microsoft system

Cygwin programs are special craft Windows programs compiled with ad hoc tools and linked to the cygwin1.dll.